# How might an intelligent and scientifically-minded RPG protagonist optimize their world?

Tags: super-powers, rpg

A highly intelligent man or woman with whatever modern or genre knowledge you like wakes up one day in an RPG world, and they are the protagonist.  They possess mystical elemental powers that are strengthened by slaying monsters.  They regularly have epic story hooks thrown at them.  Most importantly, they find various points in the world that allow them to 'save' at a specific place, and then 'restore' to the point in time that they saved with specific memories of what took place.

The world itself is medieval, and has most of the conventions one might expect in an RPG - it's mostly made up of feudal city-states ruled over by corrupt-ish monarchies and occasionally conquered by vast empires.  Most of the land is beset by wandering magical of all kinds, some of which appear to be sentient, and almost all of which are violent and dangerous.  Quality of life is low for the average person, even without the presence of the ancient evil that is presumably approaching at some point.

The protagonist is benevolent and utilitarian.  They set about attempting to improve the world's quality of life and reduce suffering as much as possible.  They don't just want to stop the ancient evil (though that might be an instrumental goal.) They want to use their newfound power to do real and active good, and ensure that the citizens of the world live as well as they possibly can.

The protagonist can (and is encouraged to) 'munchkin' their powers as much as necessary in order to achieve this goal.  They can use spells that are typically restricted to combat (such as cure spells) in any context.  They can save and restore to solve arbitrarily to explore the possibility-space around any decision, up to a limit of their own patience - for example, they could use saving to solve arbitrarily difficult math problems in an instant, or to find the perfect time to sneak into the evil overlord's palace and place botulinum toxin in his tea.  They can use genre knowledge to their advantage, though of course this may backfire once in a while.  Save and restore seems like by far the most useful power, but there might be obscure uses for other RPG powers that often go unconsidered.

What techniques might the protagonist use to improve the state of their world?  Would they try to take over the existing governments?  Try to mass-produce CURE spells and EXP for the general public?  Civilize the monster population that controls the vast majority of the arable land?

Bonus points: How might a similarly savvy evil overlord stop a character with powers like this, if they identified him or her early on?  Assume for simplicity that the protagonist only has one save 'slot' at a time, so once they've saved at a point they cannot revert to before that point.

Comment: "What does my hero do next" questions are specifically off-topic because they have objectively best answer. Aside from that, it's clear idea generation (also not ok). Please review [the help pages](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and edit your question. You've got a good start.

Comment: See [Daemon](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(novel_series)).

Comment: So... You've been reading *Log Horizon*, then?

Comment: The savvy evil overlord should pull back all his weak minions and keep them somewhere the protagonist cannot reach them, destroying his ability to level up. Then send out the drastic "super high-level hit squad" immediately, rather than allowing him to slowly gain power before taking the drastic actions.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how much you want to stick to an RPG world.  If it *really* works like an RPG world the easiest would be to level up and then kill high level monsters for [massive amounts of money](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MoneyForNothing), then use said money to buy everyone food.  In real life this would just lead to inflation not more food, but in RPG world you can buy as many potions and breads as you have money to without limit, so if you *really* stick to an RPG world there is limitless items you can buy with your money.

On a related note if hints aren't limteless then he can still kill some of the gigantic creatures and bring them back to a village to feed everyone, while removing monsters that threaten the village.

What is the cap on max level?  if he can level up enough he can become high enough level to solve almost any problems as well.  He can outlaw war and if anyone goes to war anyways show up and non-lethally defeat an entire army single handedly...but this assumes there is no level cap to limit how much stronger then the rest of the world is.

If he is smart enough he can bring our technology to the world, helping them advance past medieval rapidly, which would be a huge advantage.  if his 'int' goes up with levels he can always arrange to be smart enough.  This would take longer, but would be one of the largest gains in the long run, since the advancement will continue to help people for generations to come.

Related, since magic always violates thermodynamics he can get around limits on energy.  High enough level and a simple lightning spell could equal enough power to power lights and other devices for a long time.  Nice clean energy for all your new tech.

If the world insist on treating him as a PC then he can go around and fix problems on the presumption that anything he does *will* improve the world; because RPGs always make difficult situations simple ones where the hero makes life better for everyone.